# Switch case brackets

Tags: swift, switch-statement

Searching for some logical (not syntactical) errors in my app, just a quick question (I tried to google it, couldn't
 find the answer): 
Can you use multiple lines of code for each Case in Swift, without adding curly brackets? Like this (doggish code just to show you what I mean):

```
    switch (cardsOnTable) {
    case 2:
           card3.textColor(UIColor.blackColor())
           card3.text("Spades 2")
           // Something else
    case 3:
```

Just wondered if it is these lines that are messing my rules up. I tried adding curly brackets in the cases, but then I got an error. "Braced block of statements in an unused closure"

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can and indeed you must; but you cannot omit the `switch` curly braces, as you have done:

```
switch (cardsOnTable) { // <= required curly braces
// ...
}
```

In other words, the individual cases don't get curly braces, but the `switch` statement itself does.

Comment: Oh, the switch statement itself does have curly brackets, I should have added that, sorry. There are no syntax errors, just some logical ones. But I don't need brackets for each case then, when they have multiple lines?

Comment: Well, the "you can" could be interpreted ambiguously, you know.... Some people could have skim read my post and then went "Yes you can and must use curly brackets" But thx I guess.

Comment: I see now that you added some clear clarification at the end of your first comment, so I committed the same sin I suspected you could have done, skim reading. Thats also why my code was so doggish in the opening post I was very impatient. My apologies.

Comment: ... however the parentheses are not required ;-)

Comment: Yes, I didn't say anything against the fact that you answered my question. I don't really see the point in all these derailments, downvotes, etc. This question was not a duplicate nor easily google-solved, you answered it, and I apologized when I misread your post, Matt. I expect some courtesy back, and from the downvoters too. This question can be of benefit to other people as well, if it's not downvoted, which there's no reason now for it to be.

Thanks, Vadian. :)

Comment: Who's whining now? I have accepted and thanked people for answers in every one of my questions that were answered, as anyone can see. Even though there might often be good reasons for downvotes, there are also such a thing as downvoting because you didn't read the opening post clearly. I never asked for help about the logical errors, I stated very clearly that I simply had a quick question about the brackets, and the solution might be of great benefit to others with the same problem.

Comment: "I have accepted and thanked people for answers in every one of my questions that were answered, as anyone can see" That's nonsense. You have _never_ accepted _any_ answers. That's just a fact. Possibly you don't know what accepting an answer is.